# I don't think I overcomplicated this

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography, audio

> **To:** Bob <bbob@bobinator.com>
>   **From:** John <jjohn@johninator.com>
>
> **Title:** I don't think I overcomplicated this
>
> Hey! I made a "challenge" for my kids. Do you think it's alright for them?
>   [image: image of duck]
>   - John

---

*Original image sourced from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatidae)*

Comment: I see the audio tag but where is the audio here? Is it intended to be the "quack" that the duck makes?

Comment: @Moose MASSIVE HINT: The audio's hidden in the image.

Comment: What should we find? I got an [audio file from wiki page!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Anas_platyrhynchos_-_Mallard_-_XC62258.ogg) is it related ?

Comment: While the tags are pretty strong hints what to do, puzzles are generally more fun if you don't have to guess what your goal is. (Exceptions possible.) you could improve the puzzle and its reception by adding a few "The task is to..." Lines at the bottom. Only if this would totally spoil you puzzle should you 'just throw it out' without anything. (And in such a case, the enigmatic-puzzle tag would become appropriate.)

Comment: is "alright" spelled on purpose that way, or could it be "all right" as well?

Comment: @Raystafarian could be "all right"

Comment: steganography tag is inappropriate ! It says : "Hidden messages concealed in otherwise unsuspicious pictures" but a duck picture will always be suspicious to me

Comment: @Lordofdark *especially* Mallards and American Black ducks..

Comment: @Raystafarian darn mallards...

Comment: @Lordofdark do you have anatidaephobia?

Comment: @BmyGuest I added the enigmatic tag because I believe this puzzle would be spoiled if I told people what to do

Comment: @SahibPrime, could you give a Hint? its been 2 months

Comment: @SahibPrime, could you give a hint? It's been 8 months.

Comment: Imgur compresses images, so could the embedded audio have been affected? 9.8 kb isn't a lot of space for an audio file.

Comment: The image when run through Audacity gives audio lasting a fraction of a second. I wasn't able to alter or stretch anything useful out of it, just noise. The waveform doesn't give up any information either.

I also did the same with the original photo (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Male_mallard_duck_2.jpg) just in case the wiki link was a clue. Still nothing.

Comment: please make sure that you can decode the image that you get when you right click and select save image as. As qwewqa notes, imgur compresses images, so you need to make sure this is still solvable.

Comment: hey can we have a hint or an answer on this suspicious duck ?

Comment: sadly I've happened to forgot any hints since this was so long ago, so now this is more an enigmatic puzzle than ever... although qwewqa and micsthepick might be right in that imgur removed all audio. but there was audio in the image, and I believe it was morse code

Comment: 2 years *must* be legit wait time for some hints...

Comment: @InitializeSahib wait wat. how can you have audio in the image. and/or how would imgur remove it anyway

Comment: can you please upload the original to google drive or onedrive?

Comment: it's been 3 years and i've lost the original image in the meanwhile, sorry

Comment: After reading the comments, 1, this **is** over complicated and 2, I'm sad about people's opinions about ducks.